# Используется ли нерекурсивная реализация быстрой сортировки на реальных проектах?

Tags: сортировка, производительность

Мой препод по проге сильно фанатеет от нерекурсивной быстрой сортировки, требует использовать только её, говорит что она прям гораздо эффективнее. Действительно ли это так, и используется ли такая реализация в настоящей работе в компаниях или классическая рекурсивная реализация все таки популярнее?

Comment: Все стандартные алгоритмы уже лет 30 реализованы в библиотеках и вручную не пишутся в реальной работе. Тем не менее знать и учить это надо, ваш преподаватель прав. Образование подразумевает изучение общей системы, и теории, а не только освоение навыков как лопатой махать отсюда и до забора.

Comment: Так в библиотеках используется нерекурсивная реализация?

Comment: Используется, рекурсия ест много памяти.

Comment: Откатил вопрос в исходное состояние, т.к. правка Space Researcher меняет смысл вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Нерекурсивные варианты рекурсивных алгоритмов в реальности используются довольно редко, поскольку зачастую они сводятся просто к ручной реализации стека (то, что называется "закат солнца вручную"). Помимо увеличения сложности алгоритма на пустом месте, подобный подход требует выделить под этот ручной стек область памяти неизвестного заранее размера, а лишнее динамическое выделение памяти - это всегда плохо.

Чаще всего используют "полурекурсивные" варианты, в котором одна из веток сортируется рекурсивно, а вторая - в цикле. Условная схема:

```
fn sort(array, low, hi) {
    while (low < hi) {
        middle = partition(array, low, high);
        sort(array, low, middle); // левая ветка сортируется рекурсивно
        low = middle; // правая ветка сортируется без рекурсии
    }
}
```

Также популярным "трюком" является переключение на другие алгоритмы при выполнении некоторых условий, а именно на сортировку вставками для малых массивов и на пирамидальную сортировку при превышении лимита рекурсии.

Алгоритм быстрой сортировки, использующий этот трюк, называется Introsort.

Вот результаты быстрого анализа стандартных библиотек:

1. C# - используется полурекурсивный Introsort;
2. Java - используется полурекурсивный Dual Pivot Quicksort (тоже с трюками);
3. C++ - используется полурекурсивный Introsort;
4. Python - используется вообще TimSort, относящийся к классу сортировок слиянием.

Как видно, нерекурсивная быстрая сортировка не используется. И чистая классическая тоже не используется.

Answer (score 1):

Она действительно может быть эффективнее. Всё зависит от обстоятельств и от того, что вы вкладываете в это слово (в слово эффективнее). Дело в том, что если машина сильно ограничена по памяти, то вызов функции рекурсивно - будет существенной нагрузкой, а значит применение нерекурсивной реализации более целесообразно. В то же время, [можно найти информацию](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu-sn&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5), что рекурсия работает быстрее (то есть с точки зрения скорости работы имеет преимущество), **хотя так ли это в конкретном случае - неизвестно, по крайней мере до тех пор, пока мы говорим общими словами.** 
Если вам это действительно интересно, вы можете провести сравнение (вот [пример](http://www.hpcc.unn.ru/?dir=862), или [вот](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/marginalnye-svoystva-prostyh-sortirovok-tselochislennyh-massivov/viewer)), промоделировав работу этих 2 алгоритмов в разных условиях, выявить особенности. Результаты оформить в виде научной статьи, отправить в какой-нибудь журнал или выступить на студенческой научной конференции, можете опубликовать на хабре и поделиться тут. Только не забудьте, что в вашем исследовании должна быть научная новизна (быть может такое исследование уже есть, ищите).

Вдобавок скажу, что академическое образование направлено прежде всего на расширение кругозора, а не на то, чтобы сделать из вас ремесленника. Образование знакомит с разными областями предметной области и учит искать подходы к решению проблемы, учит учиться, поэтому в рамках учебной деятельности ваш преподаватель правильно делает, что знакомит вас с алгоритмами с разных сторон.

Comment: "В то же время, принято считать, что рекурсия работает быстрее" - во-первых нет, не принято считать, во-вторых нет, не работает быстрее, в-третьих приведенная ссылка на поиск не подтверждает ваше утверждение. Рекурсию часто проще/быстрее реализовать, но в общем случае обычный цикл (та же хвостовая рекурсия развернутая в цикл) будет работать быстрее.

Comment: Вы не можете утверждать, что она не работает быстрее, у вас нет данных(или на что вы опирались , какие доводы?) и это ооочень обобщенное высказывание - есть разные условия и нет смысла выпадать в какую-либо крайность и утверждать, что рекурсия быстрее не работает.
Далее, под той ссылкой -ответ, в котором написано : "В этом случае рекурсия будет выполняться быстрее аналогичного цикла.". Большинство сделает ошибочный вывод:"рекурсия быстрее", это я и вложил в "принято считать", а вот кем принято, где принято, это всё тоже общие слова. Я это написал, чтобы дать понять, что не всё однозначно

Comment: "у вас нет данных" - у меня есть знания. Я знаю как будет работать скомпилированный рекурсивный код и соответствующий по смыслу код в виде цикла, я могу оценить длительность операций. "Большинство сделает ошибочный вывод:"рекурсия быстрее", это я и вложил в "принято считать", а вот кем принято, где принято, это всё тоже общие слова" - то есть вы свое частное мнение экстраполируете на неограниченное число лиц ("большинство", (кем-то) "принято считать"), по факту я впервые вижу такое предположение, и ваше предположение о большинстве и о том как принято считать ни на чем не основано.

Comment: Рекурсию бывает проще реализовать, код получается короче - это правда. Но рекурсия всегда медленнее, просто потому, что для вызова функции нужно пихать данные в стек и делать вызов функции, а если мы делаем тоже самое циклом, то ничего этого не надо. И на уровне процессора работа со стеком всегда медленнее, чем работа с регистрами (в которых обычно лежат переменные цикла), простая логика. И на уровне языков программирования это соотношение тоже сохраняется. И я не слышал никогда, чтобы кто-то считал рекурсию более быстрой.

Comment: @insolor "у меня есть зания" - такой же личный опыт. 

Этими словами я показывал то, что нельзя мир красить в черное и белое и нужно сначала провести исследование, а потом делать вывод.  Я нигде не сказал что рекурсия быстрее или медленнее, я лишь показал, что чтобы сделать вывод, нужно разобраться в конкретной ситуации. Ответ гугла по запросу, мог кого-то ввести в заблуждение, ведь он первый, именно во избежание этого я привёл эту ссылку. С таким же успехом вместо "принято считать" , я мог написать "можно найти информацию", это те же общие слова.

Comment: @CrazyElf слова принято считать опять таки не говорят кем принято считать и где.

Этими словами я показывал то, что нельзя мир красить в черное и белое и нужно сначала провести исследование, а потом делать вывод. Я нигде не сказал что рекурсия быстрее или медленнее, я лишь показал, что чтобы сделать вывод, нужно разобраться в конкретной ситуации. Ответ гугла по запросу, мог кого-то ввести в заблуждение, ведь он первый, именно во избежание этого я привёл эту ссылку. С таким же успехом вместо "принято считать" , я мог написать "можно найти информацию", это те же общие слова.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher, рекурсия хуже даже не из-за ограничений по памяти, а из-за того, что при рекурсии потребуется сохранять-восстанавливать регистры.  /  (Разумно реализованный алгоритм быстрой сортировки будет сортировать сначала более короткий отрезок, а второй отложит в стек (не важно, реальный (в случае рекурсии) или моделирууемый (при итеративной реализации)))